# Where to ask non-programming question about Mac OS X?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where do I ask non-programming questions about Mac OS X? Such as how to create a right-click-menu shortcut to create new folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is for power users (hardware and software).  I don't see anything in their on-topic list that specifies how advanced questions should be, so I don't know if they would consider this to be too basic.  You could either go ahead and ask, or pop into their chat room first and ask about it there.